Multilingual Documents, Furigana using Ruby creating spacing too large in Lualatex (Japanese, Arabic, English)
I'm trying to create a multilingual document in Lualatex that includes Ruby Furigana, i.e. transliterations above Kanji or other characters.
I'll post the MWE below, but my problem is that I usually need to include line spacing that's 1.5 or double. However, this creates large spacing between the Furigana and their respective characters, making it look like the text belongs to the line above, rather than the correct ones.
Is it possible to fix this?
Is there a way to use other non-Western scripts, like Arabic or Sanskrit without having to include them in curly brackets, I saw something like     \sanskritfont to introduce that script.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.9in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{luatexja} % Load luatexja for Japanese
\usepackage{ruby} % Ruby text for furigana

\usepackage{fontspec} % Use fontspec for font settings
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec} % Enable fontspec for CJK fonts
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % Set your main Latin font
\setmainjfont{Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN} % Set your Japanese font (Noto Sans CJK)
\usepackage{ruby} % Ruby text for furigana
\renewcommand{\rubysep}{0.25ex} % Adjust ruby text separation
\newcommand{\myruby}[2]{\ruby{#1}{\raisebox{0.1mm}{\fontsize{8}{12}\selectfont #2}}}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{spacing}{2}
    
    \section*{English}
    This is a sample text in English. LuaLaTeX allows for writing in multiple languages in a single document.
    
    \section*{Japanese (日本語)}

    これは日本語のサンプルテキストです。LuaLaTeXを使って、同じドキュメント内で複数の言語を使用できます。
        これは\myruby{漢字}{かんじ}の例です。
    \end{spacing}

    
\end{document}



I haven't tried it but maybe making the distance inside the \raisebox negative in \myruby (maybe \raisebox{-0.2mm}{...} or so) would work?

That just seems to modify the distance to the line above, which unfortunately doesn't help me as it would mess with the regular formatting. Thanks though

making the \rubysep negative would work. E.g. \renewcommand{\rubysep}{\dimexpr0.25ex-0.5\baselineskip\relax}. But imho you should report that to ruby, they could add \def\baselinestretch{1}\@currsize  at the begin of ruby definition (in the group) to force singlespacing.

\renewcommand{\rubysep}{\dimexpr0.25ex-0.5\baselineskip\relax} works! Thanks! If you tell me where to report that, I can :)
